# TeX Packages supported?

Tags: support, mathjax

It is possible to do useful things with external $\TeX$ packages; but what packages are supported (and which do not need an explicit `\require{…}`)? I could only find only three packages with explicit `\require{…}` documented by example in the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); two are used below.

Example: to get this  
$\require{AMScd} \require{cancel}
\begin{CD}
     A @>           x    >>      B\\
@V y V V    \xcancel\LaTeX    @V V u V\\
     C @>>          v     >      D
\end{CD}$
  we can use this:

```
$\require{AMScd} \require{cancel}
\begin{CD}
     A @>           x    >>      B\\
@V y V V    \xcancel\LaTeX    @V V u V\\
     C @>>          v     >      D
\end{CD}$
```

Comment: See [this post on chemestry.se](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/what-additional-formatting-features-are-available-to-mathjax-possibly-via-requ) for more details.

Comment: This seems somewhat related, too: [Poll for MathJax macros that should be automatically loaded](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3667).

Answer (score 5):

There is a [list of extensions here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=%5Crequire#tex-and-latex-extensions). Some are [included already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251229). They are

> action

$$\require{action}\mathtip{\text{hover over this}}{e^x}$$

> amsMath/amsSymbols (already included)

\begin{align}
 &\text{align} \\
 &\text{equations!}
\end{align}

> amsCD

$$\begin{CD}
     A @>           x    >>      B\\
@V y V V       @V V u V\\
     C @>>          v     >      D
\end{CD}$$

> autobold

**bolds math automatically $\require{autobold} x + y$**

> BBox (doesn't need a `\require`?)

$$\bbox[red]{x+y}$$

> begingroup

see [The scope of `\newcommand` is the entire page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4130/437127)

> cancel

$$\require{cancel} \cancel{x + y}$$

> color

MathJax has a `\color` built-in. See the MathJax docs or [this thread](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3646) for more information on what the color package does.

> enclose

$$\require{enclose} \enclose{circle}{~~~x+y+z~~~}$$

> extpfeil

$$\require{extpfeil} \Newextarrow{\xrightharpoonup}{5,10}{0x21C0} X \xrightharpoonup{f} Y$$

> html

This one's blocked.

> mhchem

$$\require{mhchem} \ce{C6H5-CHO}
\ce{$A$ ->[\ce{+H2O}] $B$}
\ce{SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v}$$

> noErrors (already included?)

Not sure what this does

> noUndefined (already included)

$$\badcommand$$

> unicode (doesn't need a `\require`)

$$\unicode[.55,0.05]{x22D6}$$

> autoload-all

loads everything

---

Right click on the math and select "Show Math As->TeX Commands" to see what commands were used.