# How does one add missing latex commands or see all available commands in math exchange site?

Tags: support, mathjax

I wanted to write the `\underbar` in the [mathexchange site][1], but it wasn't possible when using `\underbar{}`. Is it possible to define my own commands for the math exchange site or how do I get access to all the available symbols for the site?

I'm not interested in debating to add features, I just want

1. to use the command I want to use

and

2. know a reference of all the available commands for future reference.

Comment: Closely related: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26609/tex-packages-supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX support on this site is provided by [MathJaX](https://www.mathjax.org/).

MathJaX documentation has a long list of [Supported LaTeX commands](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands). Note that some of them are provided by extensions, as indicated on the list -- those extensions are not enabled here.

Comment: All extensions in MathJax's core repository (ie that list) can be `\require`d.